# Wicket: stateful vs. stateless components

Tags: wicket, stateless, stateful

It looks like for some reason Wicket considers some of our components as stateful and hence some pages become stateful as well. What makes Wicket assume a component as not stateless? If the goal is to make as much as stateless as possible, what are some *Don'ts* (and what to use instead)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually Ajax components and behaviors make the page stateful. You can use WicketStuff-Stateless library to replace them with stateless versions.

Apart from this you should replace usage of `Form` component with `StatelessForm` and `Link` with `StatelessLink`.

You can use wicket-devutils' `StatelessChecker` to find out which component/behavior makes the page stateful.

Comment: We don't use Ajax components. Is there some drawback/limitation when using Form/Link instead of StatelessForm/StatelessLink?

Comment: The `StatelessXyz` versions actually extend from the respective `Xyz` components. They just try to preserve as much context information as possible for the next destination, where context means the page parameters.